# SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (30 minutes)

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm trying to get my code to output in the following format:

```
2015-05-24 19:00 | 1
2015-04-24 19:30 | 3
2015-04-24 10:39 | 51
```

My table

```
rm_id | date
1 | 1298027046
2 | 1298027100
```

What should I do a SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Divide the timestamps by 1800 (30 minutes * 60 seconds/minute) to get the grouping.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1800 * FLOOR(date/1800)) AS period_start, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY period_start
```

Comment: Ah, so SO *is* a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks. It's great. still I need to add the condition of two dates. The first parameter will be administered and the second is the first + 7 days